# Image is not upload and saving on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to upload the file using Nodejs, I am sending file from my nest js front end. Even though I am getting file on the req.body, upload function is not working.

[image]

Only default value is setting on the cover picture. All other fields are saving fine but not the file.

```
const { Schema, validate } = require("clean-schema");

const PostModel = new Schema({
  _id: {
    constant: true,
    value: generatePostId,
    onDelete: deleteAllBookmarks,
    onSuccess: handleSuccess,
  },
  body: { required: true, validator: validatePostBody },

  coverPicture: {
    default: { url: "", metadata: {} },
    dependent: true,
    dependsOn: "_setCoverPicture",
    resolver: ({ context: { _setCoverPicture } }) => ({
      url: _setCoverPicture.url,
    }),
  },
  _setCoverPicture: {
    alias: "coverPicture",
    virtual: true,
    shouldInit: false,
    validator: validateFile,
    onFailure: onFailure("coverPicture"),
    sanitizer: sanitizeFile("_setCoverPicture", "coverPicture"),
  },
}).getModel();

const uploadImage = ({ pageId, path }) => {
  const filePath = getFilePath(TEMP_FILE_UPLOAD_DIR)(path);

  cutFile(path, `public/static/pages/${pageId}/${filePath}`);

  return { url: `/static/pages/${pageId}/${filePath}` };
};

function onFailure(fileField) {
  return ({ context }) => {
    const path = context[fileField].path;

    if (path) deleteFile(path);
  };
}

function sanitizeFile(setterField, fileField) {
  return ({ context }) => {
    const { _id: pageId } = context;

    const file = context[setterField];

    const oldFile = context[fileField];

    const res = file?.unset
      ? { url: "" }
      : uploadImage({ pageId, path: file.path });

    // remove old image during updates
    if (oldFile?.url) removeImage({ url: oldFile.url });

    return { url: String(res.url) };
  };
}

function validateFile(file) {
  if (file == "") return { valid: true, validated: { unset: true } };

  if (!file || typeof file != "object") return FILE_ERROR;

  const _path = validateString("", { maxLength: 1000 })(file?.path);
  if (!_path.valid) return FILE_ERROR;

  const _size = validateNumber("", {
    range: { bounds: [0, MAX_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES] },
  })(file?.size);
  if (!_size.valid) return FILE_ERROR;

  const path = String(_path.validated),
    size = Number(_size.validated);

  return { valid: true, validated: { path, size } };
}

module.exports = { PostModel, resolveReactions, validateSetReaction };
```

Create Post Function

```
  const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    const isQuestion = req.body.isQuestion === "true";
    const { data, error } = await PostModel.create({
      ...req.body,
      isQuestion,
      createdBy: req.user._id,
    });

    console.log(data);

    if (error) return res.status(400).json({ data: error, success: false });

    const post = await postDb.create(data);

    res.status(200).json({ data: post, success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error creating post:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ data: "An Error occured", success: false });
  }
};
```

Here is that console log.

[image]

Comment: How do you plan to store your image? Did you store your image in any cloud service and just want to store the filepath in mongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload the image to MongoDB, you should upload it first to some service like [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/en/s3/) from Amazon, then store the URL of the image's location as `string`.

Other alternative is [GridFS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/) from MongoDB